ShareThis buttons disappear in Chrome after refresh
I'm having issue in the Chrome browser with ShareThis buttons disappear after refresh of the page.
On the other hand, in Firefox everything works as expected, that is: all the buttons stay visible even after the refresh of the page.
I have to completely close Chrome and reopen it again so that the ShareThis buttons are back, but as soon as I refresh the page they disappear once again until the next restart of the Chrome.
Does anyone know why is this - how to solve this issue, or if this is some common Chrome bug?
